# Performance Issue with JS in Chrome (V8)

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, google-chrome

I have the following simple code :

```
var objTest = function(){
    this.recupOpt = function(){
        return [1, 2];
    };

    this.recup = function(){
        return new Array(1,2);
    };
};
```

According to personal tests and this one http://jsperf.com/performance-js-chrome-array, I've observed the method recupOpt is slower than the recup one (in Chrome at least, similar performance in Firefox) when called after the object creation.

I'm quite surprised of such result since I've read everywhere [] is more efficient than new Array because this syntax is dedicated to the array creation.

However, when I perform only one allocation then I only test the call, the performance is better with the [] (http://jsperf.com/performance-js-chrome-array-2).

It seems the call recupOpt cost more when it is call from a new object, but is more efficient when this object has already been used several times.

Do you have any idea of the reason of these results?

Thank you

Comment: i think this has changed i think `[]` and `{}` are now both handled by the JSON style parser (i'm not saying it's JSON.parse) built into the engine to it has to use it, if you tried it in IE6 i think you would find that what you have read is correct just nowerdays it's not the case and `recup` is easier to read :)